# How to replace the grill emblem of a Fiat Croma?

Tags: replace, fiat, replacements

This Christmas we bought a replacement front grill emblem of a Fiat Croma (2009), without really thinking on beforehand how this should be done.

Now, the gift is received, and the receiver wants to replace the emblem, but doesn't know how. I've searched, but cannot find a guide or something like that. Can anyone explain how the emblem should be replaced?

Photos of the replacement emblem:

[image: front]

[image: back]

The text on the back says "B6 32"

Comment: Anyway to get a picture of the grill are where it would go and the emblem itself? I haven't done this specifically, but with those two pics, I'm sure I could help you suss it out.

Comment: Thanks for the reaction, I included pictures of the front and back of the emblem, but cannot include any pictures of the grill itself, but it is one like [this](http://static.classistatic.de/imagegallery/fiat/croma/fiat-croma-fia_cro_09_ecologic_5.jpg)

Comment: What happened to the original badge?

Comment: It has a lot of wear and tear, due to weather conditions probably. The red logo and text has faded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears from the images this should be a fairly simple job. The small center tab protruding from the back should have an interference washer (I don't know what to call it, exactly) which will be placed over it to positively capture it and hold the part in place. The first thing you need to do is get the old badge off. To do this, you'll need to place a small thin bladed screwdriver between the interference washer and the grill, working your way around it in small increments to get it to come off of the old badge's tab. Be careful while doing this as you'll need the washer to fit the new badge. Once it's off of the tab, pull the emblem off of the grill. Fit the new badge onto the grill and place the interference washer onto the new tab, sliding it on until the badge is snug and the washer is fairly flat against the grill.

Comment: There is some sort of rifling in the replacement part, that is not fastened in this way, is that correct?

Comment: @Mathias711 Are you talking about the two little tabs towards the top of the emblem?

Comment: No, the tab in the middle, just velo with the 4 characters of text. By the way, thanks for helping me out!

Comment: There may be some ridges on the center post. If so, this would be to help the interference washer hold on better. You should still be able to get the washer to pull away from it. If you cannot, don't be afraid to break the tab off of the old one, being sure to maintain positive control of the pin. You loose the washer and you've got nothing to affix the new badge to the grill with.

Comment: If the old badge isn't as I've explained, let me know and we can better help you. I'm just rolling on what I've worked with in the past.

Comment: Thanks for the information! We will try this out when we've got time for this and keep you updated!